# Is it possible for there to be infinitely many solutions in this system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$x+(4/3)z=1$$
$$y-(1/6)z=1/2$$
$$z=(2-a)/(-2-a^2)$$
Where *a* is a constant

I realize that we need all three equations to be equal for there to be infinitely many solutions. The question wants the answer in terms of *a*. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac43z$ and $\frac16z$, or $\frac4{3z}$ and $\frac1{6z}$?

Comment: I made the proper edits, sorry about that! (4/3)z and (1/6)z

Comment: The third equation is a formula for $z$ solely in terms of $a$. The first and second are easy to rearrange to give formulas for $x$ and $y$ respectively in terms of $z$ and hence using the third equation in terms of $a$. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are easily written in terms of $z$, and if $a$ is constant, $z$ is already given in terms of $a$. So...there is a unique solution for any real $a$.

Specifically:
$$x = 1-\tfrac43(2-a)/(-2-a^2)$$
$$y = \tfrac12+\tfrac16(2-a)/(-2-a^2)$$
$$z = (2-a)/(-2-a^2)$$